# Getting error : This type of error is only supported in new experimental ABI Encoder while passing struct inside function

Tags: solidity, abi, experimental-features

How can I pass struct to Function I tried doing it but all in vain

```
struct testSruct
{

    uint size;
} 

function testFunc(  testSruct test) public returns(bool replaced)
{
    return true;
}
```

Getting error :

> This type of error is only supported in new experimental ABI Encoder

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a `struct` in/out of a function without using the experimental ABI encoder, which you should not do outside of experimentation.

What you *can* do is pass the individual members.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract ABI {

    struct TestStruct {
        uint size;
    } 

    function testFunc(uint test) public pure returns(bool replaced) {
        return test == 0;
    }
}
```

With the experimental ABI:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2; // This will generate a cautionary warning.

contract ABI {

    struct TestStruct {
        uint size;
    } 

    function testFunc(TestStruct memory test) public pure returns(bool replaced) {
        return test.size == 0;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.